# Updating SQL with Coalesce / Tracking Updated Records in Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just for fun I decided to write code that lists all tables and the number of records that have been updated today (Using SQL Server). For example:

```
TableName   ModifiedToday

table1      0

table2      5

table3      2
```

The first step was creating a temp table with all of the table names in the database containing the date_modified field:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT      
            t.name AS 'TableName'
        ,-1 AS 'ModifiedToday'
            into #temp
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%date_modified%'
ORDER BY    TableName
```

Next I am trying to perform updates on the temp table, based on the contents of the tables. However, I am not as familiar with COALESCE or looping in SQL and struggling to update using the table name. Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @tname varchar(200) = ''

WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE ModifiedToday = -1) >0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE #temp  
        SET @tname = TableName,
         ModifiedToday = (COALESCE(CHAR(500), '') + 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+ @tname + ' WHERE DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),isnull(date_modified,0)) = 0')
        WHERE @tname = TableName
    BREAK
END
```

Comment: I suspect you don't actually want to use COALESCE here. Are you just trying to update the table with the row count returned by the sub-query you have there for each table?

If that's the case then I think you'll need to use some dynamic sql here.

Comment: Yes, I'm not attached to using COALESCE but have been using it in order to pull the table name from the column value. I wasn't able to find another workaround for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you - you can populate a list of table names into a SYSNAME column in your temp table, insert the list of table names into a table variable, and then loop through the table variable and execute some dynamic sql to get the count from each table.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #temp ( TableName SYSNAME, ModifiedToday INT )

INSERT INTO #temp ( TableName, ModifiedToday )
SELECT      
            t.name AS 'TableName'
            ,-1 AS 'ModifiedToday'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name = 'date_modified' --changed this to '=' instead of 'LIKE' since you have the column name hard coded in the query below

DECLARE @SQLObjectList TABLE ( SQLObject sysname)
INSERT INTO @SQLObjectList( SQLObject) SELECT DISTINCT TableName FROM #temp WHERE ModifiedToday = -1

DECLARE @xSQLObject VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLObjectList)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @xSQLObject = SQLObject FROM @SQLObjectList 

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #temp SET ModifiedToday = 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+@xSQLObject+' WHERE DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),isnull(date_modified,0)) = 0 )
        WHERE TableName = '''+@xSQLObject+''' '

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL 
    DELETE FROM @SQLObjectList WHERE SQLObject = @xSQLObject
END 

SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

Comment: If you do want to get all column names that have a column LIKE '%date_modified%', then you would need to parameterize that column name within the dynamic sql statement the same way you do with the table name.

Comment: That works, thank you!! Had to remove the sp_executesql from the EXECUTE function

Comment: Oops - the variable declaration of @dsql should actually be NVARCHAR(MAX) - the system proc sp_executesql will only take NVARCHAR data type. Then you won't have to remove it.